# Angular 2 material with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, npm, angular2-cli

- So far I used angular 2 quickstart to create a new project.
- I decided to start using the angular 2 cli and created a new angular 2 cli project.
- Moved all my filese and installed all packages again.

Now, when I'm trying to use the angular 2 material in my CLI project, so I followed the [guide in here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs) but this is what I get:

[image]

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: did you configured your system.config.ts file for appropriate changes? I added angular2-material to my barrels array in system.config.ts file and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.primefaces.org/ultima-ng/ take a look at this one it's coming as a angular-cli application just npm install and ng serve is enough for fully functional material admin template in angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't define angular2-material in your package.json 
in `devDependencies` you should put your package and version and after npm install